# Find a basis and the dimension of this vectorspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$U=\left \{ (x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:\sum^n_{k=1}x_k =0 \right \}$

My thoughts:

**(1)** I think that $\text{dim(U)}=n-1$, but I'm not sure how to show that.

**(2)** The basis needs to be a set of independent vectors in U and every element of U is a linear combination of that set.

So using (1) and (2) I've come to the suspicion, that $(1,-1,0,...,0), (0,1,-1,0,...,0), ... ,(0,...,1,-1)$ would form a basis. Which is yet to be proven, but I have no idea how (probably showing its span is U and all vectors are independant, still though).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Good thinking so far. Can you recognise $U$ as the kernel of a linear functional?

Comment: Proving that they are independent should be straightforward from the definition. What have you tried in this direction? As for the span part, what happens when you try to write $x \in U$ as a linear combination of these vectors?

Comment: Ah, I just managed to easily prove their independence by saying, that written as a matrix A with these vectors as rows it is already in reduced row echelon form, which is equivalent to independence, which I proved earlier on my exercise sheet.
On the span part I'm working now.

Comment: Some more thoughts: I know that every linear combination of these vectors is an element of U.
Now if I could prove the dimension of U to be n-1 I would know, that they form a basis, but I don't know how to prove the dimension.

Comment: @Joey The subspace is the null space (kernel) of a one row matrix: what's the rank of this matrix? Can you apply the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: no, sorry but i haven't heard of that in the lecture yet

Answer (score 2):

The defining equation can be written

$$
x_1=-x_2-x_3-\dots-x_n
$$

You get $n-1$ solution vectors by giving each free variable the value $1$ (and $0$ to the others); for $n=4$ they would be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix},
$$

The same procedure works for general homogeneous linear systems and always gives a set of $p$ vectors, where $p$ is the number of free variables.

These vectors are *surely* linearly independent. You can see it by considering the linear mapping
$$f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^p$$
obtained by ‘removing the rows corresponding to nonfree variables’. What you get is certainly the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^p$ because of how the vectors have been built.

A general result, which can be easily proved is the following.

> *If $f\colon V\to W$ is a linear map and $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_p\}$ is a set of vectors in $V$ such that $\{f(v_1),f(v_2),\dots,f(v_p)\}$ is linearly independent, then also $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_p\}$ is linearly independent.*

Therefore the $n-1$ vectors above are linearly independent. The rank-nullity theorem will then end the computation.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=0}^{n} x_k = 0$ implies that the whole space is determined by  $n-1$ vectors. Mathematically $x_n = \sum_{n=0}^{n-1} x_k$. That is one vector is determined by linear combinations of $n-1$ vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the map $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that $f: \sum\lambda_iv_i \mapsto \sum\lambda_i $. Why rank superior bound is 1? Why is it 1 at least? Now remember $\operatorname{dim}(V)=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{Ker})+\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{Im})$. Who is the Ker?.

Obs: $U = (1, \dots, 1)^{\perp}$